# How to execute a command to all files on a sublime text project?

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I searched all over the web to find how to execute a sublime text command for all files and then save. I need to refactor my old project that has indentation issues like hard tabs.

What I want is to execute the command "expand_tabs" to the whole project. How can I do it?

Comment: I suggest that edit your title and question to better express it is about batch converting tabs to spaces. So google would send more relevant users to this thread.

Comment: Though this does work, it requires you to manually open all of the files you want to edit. Depending on the size of your project, this may be less than ideal. For something like this in the future (again depending on the number of files you want to convert), it may be better to use some script/tool external to ST to perform  the expansion. Of course, if it's just a handful of files, or you simply want to fix them as you come across them, a plugin works well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: I've turned this into a nicely documented ST plugin. Find it here: https://github.com/maliayas/SublimeText_TabToSpaceConverter

---

I've written a small plugin that does this. Put this code under "Packages/User/BatchTabToSpaceFixer.py":

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class BatchTabToSpaceFixerCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, view):
        self.run_all_views()
        # self.run_current_view()

    def is_enabled(self):
        return len(sublime.active_window().views()) > 0

    def run_all_views(self):
        for view in sublime.active_window().views():
            self.process(view)

    def run_current_view(self):
        self.process(sublime.active_window().active_view())

    def process(self, view):
        # Previous tab size
        view.run_command('set_setting', {"setting": "tab_size", "value": 3})

        # This trick will correctly convert inline (not leading) tabs.
        view.run_command('expand_tabs', {"set_translate_tabs": True})  # This will touch inline tabs
        view.run_command('unexpand_tabs', {"set_translate_tabs": True})  # This won't

        # New tab size
        view.run_command('set_setting', {"setting": "tab_size", "value": 4})

        view.run_command('expand_tabs', {"set_translate_tabs": True})
```

Then open your project files that you want to be processed. The plugin will process open tabs and leave them dirty. You can do a "Save All" once you think everything is OK.

Don't forget to edit your previous and new tab size in the code. For example my case was from 3 (as tab) to 4 (spaces). In such a case this plugin will correctly preserve vertical inline (not leading) alignments that were made using tabs.

If you wish, you can assign a shortcut key for this job:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "batch_tab_to_space_fixer"}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this – exactly what I was looking for!